# How to drag and drop multiple Files on .bat?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

Basically I am a nooby at batch and now I got an problem I can't solve even after reading all the other related posts on this topic :( 
I am trying to start an .jar file (lets call it test.jar) with two parameters. My batch file is in the same directory. 
Here comes the part I don't get:
The two parameters should be file-names from files I dragged and dropped on the .bat-file before. 
It should work like this:
I drag and drop the first file onto the .bat-file. Then I drop the second file onto the .bat-file. Now the .jar gets started and shows Both file-names.
(best it would be if the dos-Window would not be visible throu this.)
(Until now I just got it with one file but when i drop another file onto the .bat it simply start another .bat-Window.)
This is the main-Method of my .jar file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();  //build JFrame
    frame.setSize(400,400);

    JTextField t = new JTextField(); //build TextField to display the args
    t.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 100);

    if(args.length>=1){                 //if there is at least one argument, then print out the name of the file
        t.setText("First File: "+args[0]);          
        if(args.length>=2)              //if there is more then one argument, then print out the name of the files
            t.setText(t.getText()+" Second File: "+args[1]);    
        else                            //if there are not more then one argument
            t.setText(t.getText()+" 2nd Not found");        
    }else{                              //if there ist no argument
        t.setText("1st not found");
    }

    frame.add(t);       //add TextField
    frame.setVisible(true);     //set Visible
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and clean solution,try it, if i understood you correctly this is what you need:

```
@echo off
set file1=
set file2=


echo Drag and drop file one + Enter:
set /p file1=
echo.

echo Drag and drop file two + Enter:
set /p file2=
echo.

echo.&echo.
echo %file1% 
echo %file2%
echo.

java -jar FILE.jar %file1% %file2%    

pause
```

Explanation of the code:

-Make sure the two variables file1 and file2 are emptied before starting.

-Prompts to drag and drop a file, then when you press enter it stores the path of your dragged file to %file1%

-Prompts to drag and drop a file, then when you press enter it stores the path of your dragged file to %file2%

-ECHO the two variables %file1% and %file2% to make sure they are properly saved (optional, when you know it works you can remove that part)

-Run .JAR file with the two parameters previously saved (paths)

Comment: I just thought it would be better for the users to drag one file after the other but if it's just not possible like you said I think I will go with your hint of dropping both at the same time. This was actually my solution before I started thinking about one after the other. -well i guess I learned something XD Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, i just updated my answer for a solution if you ever need to drag and drop files one after the other, it could come in handy sometime! Glad i could help

Comment: Maybe you could answer me another question: How can I make it that the dos-Window isn't visible when executing my .jar file. (Because the program is actually much bigger than the code I showed above.)

Comment: Is it enough to have it run minimized (not seen on screen but icon shows in taskbar)? Or do you want it completly invisible?

Comment: Well it would be better if it's completely invisible. It would be ok if the window is minimized while the .bat code is executing and after that the window closes completely and the java code can keep running.

Comment: If you want an invisible batch file you have do a trick with a VBS to call your batch file. 
1- Save this to a "invisible.vbs" file you create: 
`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False`
2-call your .bat file with this vbs like this (paths are examples)
`wscript.exe "C:\invisible.vbs" "C:\myfile.bat"`

Comment: Mhm.. it just sais "end of order expected" (ger.: Anweisungsende erwartet). And is it still posible to drop these files onto the .vbs or .bat file? (this is the most important thing- if not I think I'll just try the solution with minimizing the window )

Comment: Example if you want to make a file that calls the other one:
START_FILE.BAT:
`@echo off&cls
if not "%1" == "min" start /MIN cmd /c %0 min & exit/b >nul 2>&1
wscript.exe "C:\invisible.vbs" "C:\FILE_WITH_COMMANDS.bat"`

This way you'll only see a VERY brief flashing window that will run MINIMIZED then launch the other actual bat file completly hidden!

Comment: Ok simply do it like this, i made these files examples to make sure you get everything OK : 
INVISIBLE.VBS : https://pastebin.com/0mdG0uug
STARTER.BAT : https://pastebin.com/AeXkJB1d 
**(make sure you have the right paths)**
MYBAT.BAT (example of your own bat file that starts the .jar with the two file paths:) https://pastebin.com/VrJmx92w
**how to use**: drag and drop the 2 files on STARTER.BAT, it will run the MYBAT hidden with the paths as arguments for your .jar! This solution works and it makes it completly hidden :) Letting you adapt it ;)

Comment: Are you dropping your two files on the files i showed you on pastebin? It's getting a bit too complicated to comment on here.

Comment: Btw. Thank you very much. Well I did everything lke 100times got right pathnames + filenames. In result it just start the .jar without any input and a dos-Window still is visible. There may be something wrong with invisible.vbs i dont know but when i start invisble.vbs manually just by clicking on it i get an error... honestly I dont want to waste your time anymore if you don't want to keep on helping an idiot like me

Comment: Well if you drop your two filles and put %1 and %2 in the starter.bat example i gave you, it will take these paths to the final bat file that calls the jar, so the arguments are there. The problem lies elsewhere and is hard to identify in this situation. Also, it's normal you get an error starting the vbs only, it's meant to be called only via batch. Glad I could help a bit :)